# How is the correct Ansible way to apply a filter and then a .split?

Tags: ansible, find

Hey im tring to apply a filter in a variable and then split it with .split, tried this:

```
- name: Register all images files to import
  find:
    paths: "{{ remote_build_path }}/{{ dependencies_directory_name }}/docker_images"
    patterns: "*"
  register: docker_images
```

Register the variables with find, either here i could get only the base name which wouldnt work.

```
- debug: var=docker_images

- name: Load image from archive and push to a private registry
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ item.path.split('/')[0] | basename  }}"
    tag: "{{ item.path.split('/')[1] | basename }} "
    load_path: "{{ item.path }}"
    source: load
  with_items: "{{ docker_images.files }}"
```

Tried to apply the | basename filter and then the split but fails

Also tried this:

```
- name: Load image from archive and push to a private registry
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ item.path.split('/')[0]   }}"
    tag: "{{ item.path.split('/')[1] }} "
    load_path: "{{ item.path }}"
    source: load
  with_items: "{{ docker_images.files | basename }}"
```

Which won't work at the with_items level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a double split works, not very elegant but still:

```
- name: Load image from archive and push to a private registry
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ item.path.split('/')[-1].split(':')[0] }}"
    tag: "{{ item.path.split('/')[-1].split(':')[1] }}"
    load_path: "{{ item.path }}"
    source: load
  with_items: "{{ docker_images.files }}"
```